# Multiple constructor implementations are not allowed

Tags: angular, typescript, d3.js, constructor

I need to display multiple d3 charts in a page. While adding the code for one chart, it works.
But showing the error for multiple charts.

```
bardata: Observable<ChartModel>;


constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.bardata = this.http.get<ChartModel>('./assets/mocdata/data.json');
    console.log('sd', this.bardata);
}


areadata: Observable<ChartModel>;


constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.areadata = this.http.get<ChartModel>('./assets/mocdata/data.json');
    console.log('sd', this.areadata);
}
```

Please help me to clear the constructor issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cant declare two constructors in the same class, you should call ngOnInit method for this porpouse.

Answer (score 1):

Just create methods for each chart and call it in the constructor like this:

```
bardata: Observable<ChartModel>;
areadata: Observable<ChartModel>;

constructor(private http: Httpclient) {
  this.getBarData();
  this.getAreaData();
}

getBarData() {
  this.bardata = this.http.get<ChartModel>('./assets/mocdata/data.json');
  console.log('sd', this.bardata);
}

getAreaData() {
  this.areadata = this.http.get<ChartModel>('./assets/mocdata/data.json');
  console.log('sd', this.areadata);
}
```

Comment: This will not compile

Comment: @Dummy why do you think so?

Comment: Because I know typescript?

Comment: @VishnuNair could you please be more specific, what output of the error does it show to you?

Comment: @MaksymShevchenko 
constructor(private http: Httpclient) changed to 
constructor(private http: HttpClient). 

Compiled!! But only showing one chart at a time.

Comment: @VishnuNair, well, you are requesting the same `data.json` file, maybe that's an issue, maybe something in your html code, could you please add more code(your html, how do you render these charts). By the way is this the component code or a service code?

Comment: <div #chart id="area-chart" (window:resize)="onResize($event)"></div>

<div #chart id="chart" (window:resize)="onResize($event)"></div>

Created components.

Comment: <my-area-chart *ngIf="areadata" [data]="areadata | async" [xlabel]="'label'" [ylabel]="'value'"></my-area-chart>

Comment: You use the same template variable `#chart` for first and for the second chart, you have to use different variables, for that

Comment: @VishnuNair whenever you add more code, you should actually update your question with additional code that you are adding here

Comment: @MaksymShevchenko I've changed #chart to #chart1 for areachart. Even now, only one chart is showing at a time

Comment: @VishnuNair you are using only `<my-area-chart>`, but there is no element for `barData` that you have defined in your component.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180358/discussion-between-vishnu-nair-and-maksym-shevchenko).

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like that

```
bardata: Observable<ChartModel>;
areadata: Observable<ChartModel>;

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.bardata = this.http.get<ChartModel>('./assets/mocdata/data.json');
    console.log('sd', this.bardata);

    this.areadata = this.http.get<ChartModel>('./assets/mocdata/data.json');
    console.log('sd', this.areadata);
}
```

Comment: this one compiles, but only one chart is viewable